# pandas.errors.ParserError: Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I am getting a ParserError when I am trying to read a csv file using Pandas. Given below is the error and the data set that threw this error.

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 10 fields in line 8, saw 11. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Given below is the line 8 that has this error

```
10/29/18 10:20,85505306,    Scott,20181029102023-file.csv,  22.49,-12.18,CITY,,12:15.0,51:00.0,ABCD,9898,320,D231
```

I am reading the csv using the below command:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv'), index = False)
```

Sample output of the csv file:

```
File_Received_Time  Label1  City    FileName    Label2  Label3  State   Unnamed: 12 cTimestamp  dTimestamp  Label4  Label5  Label6  Label7  Label8
10/29/18 10:20  56776   Paris   file1.csv   29  29  IL      29-10-2018 04:11:11     COL06   620 398 516 451
10/29/18 10:20  46069   Hongkong    file2.csv   61  58  VA      29-10-2018 04:03:17 28-10-2018 05:58:00 COL06   576 645 349 374
10/29/18 10:20  47240   Sydney  file3.csv   43  42  IL      29-10-2018 04:12:46     COL06   534 2047    56831   372
10/29/18 10:20  47432   NewYork file4.csv   55  61  OH          28-10-2018 09:01:00 COL06   514 2354    640 633
10/29/18 10:20  41794   London  file5.csv   39  29          29-10-2018 04:12:46 28-10-2018 09:01:00 COL06   470 2354    56831   550
10/29/18 10:20  49643   LA  file6.csv   55  43  TX      29-10-2018 04:05:18     COL06   523 2301    53942   403
10/29/18 10:20  54700   Shangai file7.csv   37  29  AZ      29-10-2018 04:12:15 28-10-2018 12:51:00 COL06   569 2683    53642   538
10/29/18 10:20  37134   Singapore   file8.csv   53  62  AZ      29-10-2018 04:09:16     COL06   560 391 54541   542
10/29/18 10:20  51144   Taiwan  file9.csv   43  33  TX      29-10-2018 04:12:15     COL06   469 472 458 481
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your `csv` file?

Comment: @MayankPorwal have updated with a sample view of the first few rows of the csv

Comment: @Alex, I have updated with a sample few rows of the csv file

Comment: @darkhorse You wrote, `I am reading the csv using the below command: df.to_csv('file.csv'), index = False)`. This command does not read, it writes to csv. For reading a `csv` , please use `read_csv`.

Answer (score 9):

You can solve the `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used` by using:

```
df = pd.read_csv("train.tsv",index_col = False,sep="\t")
```

[image: Example working code in Jupyter]

Comment: Helped in my case.

Comment: index_col = False helped for me

Answer (score 5):

Seems the Python Engine is the problem try reading with pandas.read_csv and set delim_whitespace=True

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error message. I have removed double quotes from the file and that has solved the problem. I have used the below line in the terminal:

cat merged.csv | tr “”” “o” > merged.tsv

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So,

- You are using `to_csv` instead of `read_csv`.  See Mayank Porwal comment & answer.
- Your data may not be properly formatted.  CSV means *Comma Separated Values*, so separe them with commas before using `read_csv` (not sure of the dataset you use in your own tests, your question is misleading on that point).
- For the core problem, carefully check the number of fields you have on each row.    You should have the same number on each row.  This may explain why you get that error.